# Unable to read two dimensional array format correctly from textfile in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble reading a two dimensional array format from file to my program. It's supposed to read the format like this and store each character as a class HvitRute or SvartRute depending on what character it is ('#' or '.') They both extend Rute.

Format:

```
13 13
#############
..#.........#
#.#######.###
#...#...#.#.#
###.#.#.###.#
#.#.#.#.....#
#.#.#.#######
#...#.......#
#.#########.#
#.#.........#
#.#.#######.#
#...#........
#############
```

Is there any logic error to my algorithm that im missing? Thanks!
    //Code starts here

```
Rute[][] labyrinth;

public void readFromFile(File file) throws Exception{
  Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
  String rows = in.nextLine();
  String[] size = rows.split(" ");
  int y = Integer.parseInt(size[0]); int x = Integer.parseInt(size[1]);
  labyrinth = new Rute[y][x];
  int index = 0;

  while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String inn = in.nextLine();
    int secondIndex = 0;

    for(int i = secondIndex; i < y; i++){
      switch(inn.charAt(secondIndex)){
        case '#': labyrint[index][secondIndex] = new HvitRute('#');
                  break;
        case '.': labyrint[index][secondIndex] = new SvartRute(' ');
                  break;
        default : System.out.println("Feil symbol");
                  break;
      }
      secondIndex++;
    }
    index++;
  }

for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
  for(int k = 0; i < x; i++){
    if(labyrinth[i][k] != null){
      System.out.print(labyrinth[i][k].getType());
    } else {
      System.out.print("Error");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: please check using a println the x and y before the loop while and also check the inn string value

Comment: Using secondIndex in the for statement makes no sense. Should it not always start at 0 ?

Comment: Yeah, it could just as well be int i = 0, thanks.

Comment: What trouble are you having? A crash? Incorrect results? An infinite loop? Please detail your problem, including the output that you see, to give us a hint on where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
  for(int k = 0; k < x; k++){
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks @Strelok, it was just my for loop that was wrong!